# Is it possible to use google web fonts in gmail

Tags: email, gmail, google-webfonts

I want to use google web font "Over the Rainbow" when composing mail in gmail

```
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Over+the+Rainbow&v2' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Is it possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Over+the+Rainbow' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); </script>
```

Comment: At least Gmail supports webfonts for Google’s own mail. [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nsX7Y.png) is mail from 'Google+ Hangouts' - the font Roboto is included in the `<head>` of the mail.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wish the answer were different, but I do not believe it is currently possible.

I don't believe Gmail will allow you to insert a link element into the message body [(although some email clients will)](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Gmail will not allow you to run JavaScript within the message.

Comment: Google web font is simply a CSS file, outlook.com supports adding web-font when editing the email as HTML but after sending the message the font formatting vanishes

Comment: Isn't it ironic that Google Webfonts work in almost every mail client except for Google's.....

Comment: I almost went insane trying to deduce why fonts were rendering everywhere except for the gmail _web_ client. Kudos.

Comment: This answer is 10 years old and no longer valid, imo. You can add webfonts as simple CSS now.

Comment: @kontur based on your comment: are you stating that Gmail now allows webfonts, or only saying that you now can add webfonts as simple CSS in general (but Gmail still wont accept them )...? Please clarify