# Can we use google roboto fonts in gmail?

Tags: asp.net, email, html-email, google-font-api

I am using google roboto fonts in my site.I am exporting a email from my site.The google roboto fonts not reflected in gmail.
Is there is any way so that we get the roboto fonts in gmail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean for your own email inbox? Or for when people read email that you sent them?

Comment: May dublication of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516537/is-it-possible-to-use-google-web-fonts-in-gmail

Comment: I am sending email to user for there account details, and user are not see the site fonts means roboto fonts are not there.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking you need to include a css into email body in a similar way you did that for the website. The problem is that not all email clients support custom fonts and [according to this](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3897/), gmail does not support web fonts.

Roboto looks similar to sans-serif and I would suggest to use it for emails.

Answer (score 2):

Update for this question in 2020: Because the Gmail web app is already making use of Roboto, you can use it! (You can also do this (at least from a technical perspective) with "Google Sans". However I do not know if that is something they are OK with people doing. Google Sans is not available on Google Fonts, for example.)

Whether you want to use Roboto this way, which creates the chance for Google to change their UI and thereby how your emails look, is a separate question -- but to the original question of "can you use Roboto?", the answer is yes.

Source: https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts/

I've also tested it personally and it works.

Comment: From Castellum: *For my understanding. In the Google Web-Mail interface I do not see the Roboto Font in the selection field.

Am I missing something here?*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - You are correct that as a user using the Gmail web interface, you will not be able to select the font Roboto. However, if you are a developer crafting an HTML email, you can set Roboto as a font because it will be available in Gmail itself. Does that help clarify?