# Font not rendering - Gmail (browser) template

Tags: html, css, html-email, web-deployment, font-face

I am putting together an email template which includes the Montserrat font; however, it seems to render just about everywhere without issue except for gmail via a browser (Firefox/Chrome)!

The font renders as it should in my previews, iPad (mail), and Android (gmail). Has *anyone* come across this issue or is able to confirm that this font is disallowed via the web client to Gmail?

I have tried both the font-family (as per the Google Font's site instructions) and import methods of including the font with similar results as mentioned above.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use google web fonts in gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516537/is-it-possible-to-use-google-web-fonts-in-gmail)

Comment: Correct. It turns out that swaths of fonts are disallowed on the Gmail web interface. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail does not work with web fonts like Google fonts. Lack of web font support is an  issue with desktop Outlook 2007-2019 as well.

You will need to choose a web safe font as a backup. I created a list of supported fonts:

- https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/s94weLqj/

Good luck.

```
Stackoverflow wants posted code before I could post the link
of fonts that work in Gmail I maintain on JSFiddle.
I felt a list of fonts might be useful in choosing a fallback font.
```

Comment: The link is a list of fonts that work with Gmail and additional information, as I state in my answer. Stackoverflow will not let me post the link without posting some code.

Comment: Nice links. How about adding in the ones that are already in Gmail? Roboto and other ones? (it will make it complete for now)

Comment: There is robot and I think two more that Gmail serves in their style sheet which can be used.

Comment: I added Roboto to the list. It requires an import to work in JSFiddle. If you know f others @Syfer, please let me know.

Comment: Found the following fonts: https://jsfiddle.net/syfer/1xtp98r5/. There is also RobotDraft and 'Material Icons Extended' which I couldnt find. They have so many styles on the page.

Answer (score 1):

`font-face` property will not work in web gmail.. use `font-family` instead. you can visit below link to check which css property works in mail for email template. hope this helps . thanks

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css

Comment: Apologies... I meant font-family. I will edit my OP.

Comment: @Romanulus can you plz add you code so we can check why it is failing.  thanks